# linear algebra question about linear application

Tags: linear-algebra

Do someone know how to solve this please? 
Let E, F and G be K vector spaces. Let "f" be a linear mapping of E into F and "g" a linear mapping of F into G. Show that we have g ͦ f = 0 if and only if image of f ⊂ ker g.

I know that if g∘f=0, and we take any w in the image of f. By definition, there is some v∈E such that f(v)=w, and by assumption, we have that 
0=(g∘f)(v):=g(f(v))=g(w). What can I conclude from here?

And finally I suppose that the image of f is a subset of the kernel of g. v∈E. By assumption, we have that 
(g∘f)(v):=g(f(v))=0, (g∘f)(v):=g(f(v))=0,

Can someone give me a clear answer in a few lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. From $0 = g(w)$, you can conclude that $w \in \operatorname{ker} g$. So, you've taken an arbitrary element of $w \in \operatorname{Im} f$ (i.e. you've used nothing other than the fact it can be expressed in the form $f(v)$), and shown it belongs to $\operatorname{ker} g$. That is, you've shown $\operatorname{Im} f \subseteq \operatorname{ker} g$.

For the converse, assume $\operatorname{Im} f \subseteq \operatorname{ker} g$. That is, given any vector of the form $f(v)$, you know that $g$ will map it to $0$. It should be straightforward to show that $g \circ f = 0$.